# Get selector in Jquery delegate event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, delegates, event-handling

I have the following code

Here i have 2 selectors "td.slot" and "td.slot1" and 2 events "mouseover" and "mouseleave".

As you can see i am using `e.type` to get one of the events. Now i want to know if there is a way like `e.selector` where i can get one of the selectors

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("table").delegate('td.slot,td.slot1','mouseover mouseleave',function(e){

   var row = $(this).parent()[0];
   var rowHead = row.cells[0];
   var colHead = row.parentNode.rows[0].cells[$(this).index()];

   if (e.type == 'mouseover') {
    $(rowHead).css("background-color","orange");
    $(colHead).css("background-color","orange");    
   }
   else
   {
    $(rowHead).css("background-color","white");
    $(colHead).css("background-color","white");
   }


  });
```

Comment: Just a side-note: why write `$(this).parent()[0]` if you can write `this.parentNode`? The latter is faster, and shorter to write, but does exactly the same thing

Comment: You might be looking for `e.target`.

Comment: If you want to get the current selector you can use `$(this)`

Comment: You can use `$(this).selector`. http://api.jquery.com/selector/

Answer (score 0):

### Description

You can use `event.currentTarget`

> **event.currentTarget** The current DOM element within the event bubbling phase.

### Sample

#### html

```
<body>
    <div>div</div>
    <button>button</button>
</body>
```

#### jQuery

```
$("body").delegate('div,button','click',function(e){ 
    alert($(this));
});
```

### Check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P52cv/)

### More Information:

- [jQuery- Event Object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)